# Como puedo hacer que cuando un usuario inicie una tarea no pueda iniciar ninguna mas hasta que termine esa C# Windows Form

Tags: c#, sql, windows-forms, .net, windows

necesito ayuda llevo muchas semanas intentando solucionarlo y no se me da ninguna idea de como hacerlo ya que soy junior y me sucede que estoy trabajando en un proyecto que dejaron relativamente con muchos errores y uno de esto es que el mecánico inicia una tarea y puede iniciar otra si quiere y hay trae problemas por que sale el mecánico trabajando en mas ordenes de trabajo

Comment: Si te refieres a qué no pueda interactuar con el Form original hasta que cierre el actual, usa su función `ShowDialog`.

Comment: Hablaste de tu problema personal, ¡pero no de tu problema en el código! Muestra un [repro] de tu código: lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Es muy dificil ayudarte por que la pregunta no esta clara, podrias adjuntar un poco de codigo para ser mas claro?, lo que puedes hacer es utilizar task y await para esperar a que la tarea termine y luego inicie la siguiente.
Saludos

Answer (score 0):

No hay un ejemplo de código de lo que necesitas, pero según entiendo podrías tener un campo "Estado" para la tabla mecánico, esta la seteas con un valor cuando esté asignado a un trabajo ("A" de Asignado), y cuando se quiera asignar a un nuevo trabajo se consulta este campo, en caso de que esté asignado no se le permita asignar, o simplemente solo traes en la consulta aquellos mecánicos que no se encuentren asignados, saludos.

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/360547)